# Enable/Disable personalized fields per product in Shopify

Tags: shopify

We are looking for a way to add personalized fields to a Shopify website. The catch is that when adding a product, a choice(radio button or otherwise) should be given, and if that is selected the product has a field that prompts for customization. 40 char max.

I had a look at this: http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/how-do-I-collect-additional-information-on-the-product-page-Like-for-a-monogram-engraving-or-customization

but this adds the field to all products, and I want to be able to select the ones to customize.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You have to add conditional code in your template that will show the customization field for specific products. For example: if this item is in the collection "custom" show the additional info field. If it comes down to the specific type of variant you'll have to use javascript to insert the custom field when the correct variant is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar for another website:

http://www.ashhilton.com/collections/wedding-bands/products/10mm-asymetrical-facets-ring?variant=918711077

I would suggest using Metafields and the Shopify FD app:

http://www.shopify.freakdesign.com.au

Here's a gist for the line item loop which checks for the type of input:

https://gist.github.com/darryn/ba43e6559f76196aadb4

And here's an example of the namespace, key, and value which would be used in the metafield:

http://monosnap.com/image/LztiTvbVHa7kyWzQxx1KqWe0PffrzG

With this said, you would need to customise this gist with some javascript to show/hide the text input field depending on whether or not the user has opted for the customisation.

Hope this helps,